# Firebase Debug View Live Events from app installed from exported ipa files

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

#### What I want?

I want to see live events on Debug View of Firebase Console where the iOS app is to be installed from an exported `ipa` file. I have only two distribution method options to export my `ipa` file

1. Ad-Hoc
2. Development.

[image]

#### What I did?

I enabled debug mode following https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events#view_events_in_the_xcode_debug_console.
Also edited `Run Scheme` to Release Build Configuration with `Debug executable` checked.

[image]
[image]

#### What is the result?

I am not able to see any event on Firebase console after testing app installed from`ipa` exported for `Development` as well as `Ad-Hoc`.

#### My Question:

1. Is is possible to see **live events** from an iOS app installed from an `ipa` file?
2. If YES, what the exact configuration is to be used while exporting for `Ad-Doc` and (OR) `Development`?

Comment: Same question for me, anyone have an answer?
I see my device in DebugView when I launch app from Xcode directly, but my testers can not see there devices after installing build from App Distribution.

Comment: Hi, is the issiue solved for you?

Comment: @chandru did not find a solution till now.

Comment: I communicated with Google firebase. They replied, it cant be done.

Answer (score 5):

I too had to struggle with this and found a solution by setting the -FIRDebugEnabled flag in AppDelegate so that whenever you want to export the build it will not be ignored. I've also added the DEBUG macro so that it will only fire for DEBUG.

```
#if DEBUG
        var newArguments = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments
        newArguments.append("-FIRDebugEnabled")
        ProcessInfo.processInfo.setValue(newArguments, forKey: "arguments")
#endif
```

Also, a very important note is to add these lines of code BEFORE initialising Firebase! e.g. FirebaseApp.configure()
If not, it will fail gracefully. :)

I then exported the .ipa for Development and voila. I haven't tried using the Ad-Hoc option but I think it might work as well.

Also please consult the below link:

[How to debug Firebase on iOS AdHoc build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754848/how-to-debug-firebase-on-ios-adhoc-build)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if it's doable on a non-jailbroken device. When you launch an app from SpringBoard, it doesn't make sense to me that SpringBoard would allow additional parameters, because that's not the way how it's designed. The parameter is likely come from a debugger, which means it's debug only.